# Can I apply for a Schengen visa if my US visa expires in less than 90 days after my return?

Tags: visas, schengen

I am planning a trip to Europe from May 18 to 28. I want to go to France and Italy. My employer has applied for H1B extension but I haven't received the 797 yet. I am expecting to get it before my trip. I am in the Bay Area and I will be going to the San Francisco consulate.

Was anyone successful in getting a visa  in this situation? Which consulate did you go to?

Comment: I went to the Italian consulate at Detroit. My H1B visa was expiring within 2 months of my return to US from Schengen area. My I797 was valid for 3 years. However, the consulate refused to accept my application stating that they need US visa (and NOT I797)to have minimum 3 months validity at the time of return to US. Still trying to figure out my options.

Comment: I remember when I was on H1B the German embassy in Washington DC would also not accept my application with the i797 alone so it looks like that's typically the policy with Schengen countries. You can email various Schengen embassies as to their policies on it to see if some accept it before bothering to go there in person.

Comment: If it helps anyone. Embassy accepted the application and I got the visa. I did show the tickets to be that of onward journey to india